# Unable to upload multiple image in flutter android application

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to upload multiple image in server using android application which is builds with flutter language. Here is the code which I am trying.

```
static Future postDataWithFile(......List<File> images) async {

Map<String, String> headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
  };

var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));
  request.headers.addAll(headers);

request.fields['contact'] = insertVisitedPlace.contact;
request.fields['ownerName'] = insertVisitedPlace.ownerName;
request.fields['orgName'] = insertVisitedPlace.orgName;
request.fields['orgtype'] = insertVisitedPlace.orgType.toString();
request.fields['nextFollowup'] = insertVisitedPlace.nextFollowup ?? "";

..............................
```

Here I am use a List to store all image.

```
List<MultipartFile> allImagesAfterConvert = [];

images.forEach((image) { 
  allImagesAfterConvert.add(
    await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      'orgImages',
      image.path,
     )
  );
});
```

**Send request to server to add all images. But In the server get only one image.**

```
request.files.addAll(allImagesAfterConvert);




try {
   final response = await request
       .send()
       .timeout(Duration(seconds: timeoutSeconds), onTimeout: () {
     throw TimeoutException("Connection time out. Please try again");
   });

   return _isValidResponse(response) ? response : _error(response);
 } on SocketException {
   throw Failure("No Internet Connection");
 } on TimeoutException {
   throw Failure("Request time out");
 } on Error catch (e) {
   throw Failure(e.toString());
 }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace orgImages with orgImages[]

```
images.forEach((image) { 
  allImagesAfterConvert.add(
    await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      'orgImages[]’,  
      image.path,
     )
  );
});
```

This should work.